# Estimating optimal number of items for adaptive testing

Tags: item-response-theory

I am trying to find out what would be the optimal fixed length of a computer adaptive IRT scored ability test. I have the 2PL parameters of the items.

I think the right question to ask is:
How to estimate what is the average information gain of asking an additional question using maximum Fisher information (MFI from the package catR) criterion for selecting the additional question?

Or

How to estimate the correlation between results of test takers having done an eg. 30 item test (as the max realistic number) and tests with less number of items (again using MFI for asking another question)?

Comment: The optimal number of items depends on many things, including the underlying $theta$ terms, which you don't know. An item bank may never terminate if the underling value is too extreme, therefore it's hard to answer that. Regarding the second part, you could just take the ratio between information functions to see how much information would be lost, and translate that into standard errors to see how much less precise the test would have been if terminated earlier.

Comment: Ok. I think I will need to use something like simulateRespondents to simulate 30 item adaptive tests and draw the information function from that first. Than from 29 ... and so on.